# tidyverse do a pivot_wider with two different reshaping strategies (creating categorical and binary columns)

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

Using the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A"),
                 value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

I want to `pivot_wider` this data so that the reshaping creates two different sets of columns:

- One set where I create a bunch of binary columns that take the column names from the value columns (e.g. bin_1, bin_2 and so on) and that are coded as 0/1.
- An additional set where I create as many necessary columns to store the values in a "categorical" way. Here, id "A" has three values, so I want to create three columns cat_1, cat_2, cat_3 and for IDs B and C I want to fill them up with NAs if there's no value.

Now, I know how to create these two things separately from each other and merge them afterwards via a left_join.

**However, my question is: can it be done in one pipeline, where I do two subsequent pivot_widers? I tried, but it doesn't work (obviously because my way of copying the value column and then try to use one for the binary reshape and one for the categorial reshape is wrong).**

Any ideas?

---

Code so far that works:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(group_id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group_id,
              names_prefix = "cat_",
              values_from = value)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,
              names_prefix = "bin_",
              values_from = dummy,
              values_fill = list(dummy = 0),
              values_fn = list(dummy = length))

df <- df1 %>%
  left_join(., df2, by = "id)
```

---

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  id    cat_1 cat_2 cat_3 bin_1 bin_2 bin_3 bin_4 bin_5 bin_6
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         1     4     6     1     0     0     1     0     1
2 B         2     5    NA     0     1     0     0     1     0
3 C         3    NA    NA     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Not really. The linked question is really only about creating the binary versions (which I know how I can do). My question is really about how to do both, categorial and binary, in one step.

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can try:

```
tt <- unstack(df[2:1])
x <- cbind(t(sapply(tt, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(tt))))),
           t(+sapply(names(tt), "%in%", x=df$id)))
colnames(x) <- c(paste0("cat_", seq_len(max(lengths(tt)))),
              paste0("bin_", seq_len(nrow(df))))
x
#  cat_1 cat_2 cat_3 bin_1 bin_2 bin_3 bin_4 bin_5 bin_6
#A     1     4     6     1     0     0     1     0     1
#B     2     5    NA     0     1     0     0     1     0
#C     3    NA    NA     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of `purrr`, you could do:

```
map(.x = reduce(range(df$value), `:`),
    ~ df %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(!!paste0("bin_", .x) := as.numeric(.x %in% value))) %>%
 reduce(full_join) %>%
 mutate(cats = paste0("cat_", row_number())) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = "cats",
             values_from = "value")

  id    bin_1 bin_2 bin_3 bin_4 bin_5 bin_6 cat_1 cat_2 cat_3
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     0     0     1     0     1     1     4     6
2 B         0     1     0     0     1     0     2     5    NA
3 C         0     0     1     0     0     0     3    NA    NA
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but looking at it it also boils down to the fact that some sort of join is sneaked in. Or in other words. There's probably no way to achieve what I want with solely using pivots. But there are definitely alterantives to my current approach.

Comment: There is some join involved, but its use is quite different from yours. It probably could be solved using just pivots, but I'm not aware of such solution.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modifying your approach by reducing `df2` code and including it all in one pipe by taking advantage of the `list` and `.` trick which allows you to work on two versions of `df` in the same call.

Its not much of an improvement on what you have done but it is now all in one call. I can't think of way you can do it without a `merge/join`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  list(
    pivot_wider(., id_cols = id, 
                names_from = value,
                names_prefix = "bin_") %>% 
      mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ +(!is.na(.))), #convert to binary
    
    group_by(., id) %>%
      mutate(group_id = 1:n()) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = group_id,
                  names_prefix = "cat_",
                  values_from = value)    
  ) %>%
  .[c(2:3)] %>%
  reduce(left_join)

#   id    bin_1 bin_2 bin_3 bin_4 bin_5 bin_6 cat_1 cat_2 cat_3
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A         1     0     0     1     0     1     1     4     6
# 2 B         0     1     0     0     1     0     2     5    NA
# 3 C         0     0     1     0     0     0     3    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can join both your syntax into one without creating any intermediate object

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(group_id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group_id,
              names_prefix = "cat_",
              values_from = value) %>% left_join(df %>% mutate(dummy = 1) %>% arrange(value) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = value, 
                                                                                                             names_prefix = "bin_", 
                                                                                                             values_from = dummy, 
                                                                                                             values_fill = list(dummy = 0), 
                                                                                                             values_fn = list(dummy = length)), by = "id")

# A tibble: 3 x 10
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    cat_1 cat_2 cat_3 bin_1 bin_2 bin_3 bin_4 bin_5 bin_6
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         1     4     6     1     0     0     1     0     1
2 B         2     5    NA     0     1     0     0     1     0
3 C         3    NA    NA     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this would be one pipeline, strictly speaking. I maybe wasn't precise enough: what I wanted to know is if I can simply do two pivot_wider, one after the other. But I realize that this seems to be not possible.

Comment: Maybe that's possible too.  Let me figure out something